# Help finding motor to replace awning motor (want to jerry rig something together)

Tags: motors

The motor on my awning just bit the dust (again). This is the second time this has happened.

I'm looking to replace it with something that I can build myself, using the existing motor enclosure. You can see the exact motor I'm talking about below (amazon link). I just don't want to pay that much money for a replacement. I'd rather rip the burnt out one apart and buy a cheap motor to do the same thing.

What I'm struggling with is what motor to get that would handle a 20ft awning. And to fit in the existing enclosure, the diameter has to be 3cm.

I found the following motor, but I believe it may be way under powered to do it. Dimensions wise, it's like perfect for the enclosure that the fried motor is in.

https://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B00HDDXBEY/ref=ox_sc_act_title_1?smid=A1IQ6DRJX762AU&psc=1

Here are some pictures of the burnt out motor (removed from the enclosure):

[image: ddasd]

[image: ddasd]

**OEM Replacement motor:**

DOMETIC 3310423.209U Torsion Assembly

https://www.amazon.ca/Dometic-3310423209U-Drive-Assembly-Awning/dp/B07L3JF78D/ref=asc_df_B07L3JF78D/?tag=googleshopc0c-20&linkCode=df0&hvadid=347072134503&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=3888389780963375681&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9001077&hvtargid=pla-843687300391&psc=1

Comment: That is more gearbox than motor at that RPM. Looks like less than 20 watt motor.

Comment: @SolarMike - the only specs I got are of the image I posted above (from the original motor).

Comment: Blindly, I would suggest you get the equivalent replacement (as recommended by the manufacturer) and make sure all the friction points remain well lubricated. If the awning is binding at full extension (potential poor design), could you provide assistance by countering the bind during actuation? If you search for complaints against the awning and manufacturer and find many, then perhaps an alternate manufacturer might be in play. If possible, try contacting the motor manufacturer and describe the problem and constraints, they might make a recomendation.

Comment: The alternate motor you show may not have the proper gearbox. Original with 160:1. If it is less than this the awning will move proportionatey faster (for the same motor speed), which will likely overload the replacement motor. The wires for the replacement don't look like they could carry the required current.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After ripping it all open, I believe I can repair the existing motor. I cleaned off the commutator and brushes; but it looks like I need to replace the brushes.

The windings all look good. I tested the contacts  on the commutator with a multimeter and all were good.

I ordered new brushes; but I'm pretty confident this will fix it.

** On a side note **
I can tell that this thing was made to fail - the components around the brushes are super cheap, and I can tell it won't last long.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your original question: it's unsure. It depends on what we calculate vs what the products say

**What the products say**

The original has, according to the label, 20 InLb.

The replacement is 2.33 kg per cm, which is 2,02 LbIn, which is 24InLb.

The replacement has 4 LbIn to space compared to the original. This is likely due to the lower RPM, increasing torque (much like a pulley system. The box will go up slowly, but you'll have an easier time despite it needing the same amount of power total.).

**What we can calculate**

This is most likely the case, as the original does have much more power in Watt (12V * 1.85A vs 12V * 0.098A). From that I would calculate:

- 12V*1.85A = 22.2 W
- 22.2W with 35 revolutions per minute means 6.06NM or 4.48Lb-Ft.
- 12V*0.098A = 1.176W
- 1.176W with 25 revolutions per minute means 0.45NM or 0.33Lb-Ft.

Unfortunately I can't take inefficiencies of motors in account, but it's clear the packaging and the calculations might not align. Maybe the LbIn and InLb have accidentally been switched or something.